# Dynamic parameter passing through hyperlink in a DataGrid in asp.net(C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink, parameter-passing

```
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
        CellPadding="4">
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FileID" HeaderText="FileID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FilePath" HeaderText="FilePath" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="UploadedBy" HeaderText="CreatedBy" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedDate" HeaderText="CreatedDate" /> 


        <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="LINK" NavigateUrl="show.aspx" Text="SHOW" />


    </Columns>



      conn.Open();
             SqlDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();
             if (NAME.Equals("admin"))
             {
                 GridView1.DataSource = rdr;
                 GridView1.DataBind();
             }
             else
             {
                 GridView2.DataSource = rdr;
                 GridView2.DataBind();
             }
             rdr.Close();
```

I want to use the hyperlink in the Gridview to pass the values dynamically according to to the row it is clicked.As I'm new to this I'm not able to do that.Please anybody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add onRowCommand Event in your grid

```
OnRowCommand="OnRowCommand_GridView1"
```

Then define link Button with the CommandName and CommandArgument

```
      <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk1" runat="server" Text="DoClick"  CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("FileID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

and than on code behind

```
protected void GridView1_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

       if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {
          int MyFileID = e.CommandArgument;
       //Now Perfrom here ur desired action
       }
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Set `hyperlink NavigateUrl` property like...`NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("FileID", "show.aspx?ID={0}" %>'`

```
NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("FileID", "show.aspx?ID={0}") + "&FilePath=" + Eval("FilePath") %>'
```

Comment: It's giving error saying "Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkField does not have a DataBinding event."

Comment: Error is still there.What is DataBinding event?

Comment: I don't know, but I have tested the above solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check onRowCommand of GridView

Check the following link:
[How to get the current row in GridView Row Command Event?](http://ranafaisal.wordpress.com/2008/03/31/how-to-get-the-current-row-in-gridview-row-command-event/)

For information about row command: [GridView.RowCommand Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx)

Comment: Can you be more elaborative please.I used the DataGrid first time today please.